# Difference between Mongoose array and Javascript Array

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

Recently, I got a quite wired question on Mongoose, It's about the using of array. There is different use experience but I cannot find out any discussion or issue on this, so I tried to explain here, and ask someone know what's happened.

#### In javascript, Object is added as reference to array

```
    let existed;
    let company = { _id: "87" };
    let post = { evaluations: [] };
    let cost = 5;
    let predictDays = 1;
    let content = "8";
    if(!existed)
    {
        existed = {};
        existed.company = company._id;
        post.evaluations.push(existed);
    }

    existed.cost = cost || 99999999;
    existed.predictDays = predictDays || 100;
    existed.content = content || "";
    console.log(existed);
    console.log(post.evaluations);
```

Output:

```
{company: "87", cost: 5, predictDays: 1, content: "8"}
[{company: "87", cost: 5, predictDays: 1, content: "8"}]
```

#### In nodejs + mongoose, I got the totally different experience.

**post** *is [Document](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/documents.html)* from `findById`.

```
    let existed;
    if(!existed)
    {
        existed = {};
        existed.company = company._id;
        post.evaluations.push(existed);
        /* existed = post.evaluations.find((evaluation) => {
            return evaluation.company.toString() === company._id.toString();
        });*/ // Uncomments this would make existed get the working reference as javascript
    }
    existed.cost = cost || 99999999;
    existed.predictDays = predictDays || 100;
    existed.content = content || "";
    console.log(existed);
    console.log(post.evaluations);
```

Output:

```
{
  company: 5d655f7743e25137f8501c38,
  cost: 50,
  predictDays: 3,
  content: '123321'
}
[{"company":"5d6562bfef7d771e4815dd4f"}]
```

I cannot figure out why It's not working, but If I uncomment the code, that `find`again in array, I could get the expected result as below:

```
{
  company: 5d655f7743e25137f8501c38,
  cost: 50,
  predictDays: 3,
  content: '123321'
}
[{"company":"5d6563391fc9b65250e83988","cost":50,"predictDays":3,"content":"123321"}]
```

Did mongoose change the `push` behavior secretly? Hope It's enough infomation to point out my issue, any information is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Difference between `[{company: "87", cost: 5, predictDays: 1, content: "8"}]`  **vs** `[{"company":"5d6563391fc9b65250e83988","cost":50,"predictDays":3,"content":"123321"}]`

Comment: Make a minimal example in Javascript, so let someone use It conveniently is wrong in your experience? I cannot provide my whole backend implementation.

Answer (score 1):

I found out the [source code](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/blob/5fd75ef8f351dcfbd974389022594e5712f1dedb/lib/types/core_array.js#L620) for current version (5.6.11), and It explain why the `push` is working out of expected.

```
  /**
   * Wraps [`Array#push`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) with proper change tracking.
   *
   * @param {Object} [args...]
   * @api public
   * @method push
   * @memberOf MongooseArray
   */

  push() {
    if (this[arraySchemaSymbol] == null) {
      return _basePush.apply(this, arguments);
    }

    _checkManualPopulation(this, arguments);

    let values = [].map.call(arguments, this._mapCast, this);
    values = this[arraySchemaSymbol].applySetters(values, this[arrayParentSymbol], undefined,
      undefined, { skipDocumentArrayCast: true });
    const ret = [].push.apply(this, values);

    this._registerAtomic('$push', values);
    this._markModified();
    return ret;
  }
```

I can't understand It totally, but I tried to describe here with my conjecture.

1. Mongoose need to convert javascript object into sub-document when push a object. (I thought It checked on `save()`)
2. `MongooseArray.push()` copy object's properties to a new object, so the original reference passed from the parameter is not actually added.

It's just weak explanation, Hope someone could help to explain It better.

Answer (score 0):

Yes mongoose array's are different they have their own implementation of push , pop etc on their prototype. You can find the documentation [here](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#mongoosearray_MongooseArray-push)

Comment: Thanks for infomation, I also see this before I post, but you know the documentation nearly write nothing on `push`, so I decided to ask here :(

Comment: I thought you just wanted to know if they change behavior of push secretly. :P

Comment: Yeah, but this documentation could not convince me that the issue is exactly caused by this, maybe `source code` could explain this, but I tried my best and got lost...

Comment: `MongooseArray.prototype.push()` This means each mongoose array have these methods implemented on its prototye. I think you should read about prototypes a little.